# Usage of useCallback and setting new object state using previous state as argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider this basic form fields component with a custom form hook to handle input changes:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

const useFormInputs = (initialState = {})=> {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);
    const handleChange = useCallback(({ target: { name, value } }) => {
        setValues(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
    }, []);
    const resetFields = useCallback(() =>
        setValues(initialState), [initialState]);
    return [values, handleChange, resetFields];
};

const formFields = [
    { name: 'text', placeholder: 'Enter text...', type: 'text', text: 'Text' },
    { name: 'amount', placeholder: 'Enter Amount...', type: 'number',
        text: 'Amount (negative - expense, positive - income)' }
];

export const AddTransaction = () => {
    const [values, handleChange, resetFields] = useFormInputs({
        text: '', amount: ''
    });
    return <>
        <h3>Add new transaction</h3>
        <form>
            {formFields.map(({ text, name, ...attributes }) => {
                const inputProps = { ...attributes, name };
                return <div key={name} className="form-control">
                    <label htmlFor={name}>{text}</label>
                    <input {...inputProps} value={values[name]}
                        onChange={handleChange} />
                </div>;
            })}
            <button className="btn">Add transaction</button>
        </form>
        <button className="btn" onClick={resetFields}>Reset fields</button>
    </>;
};
```

1. Is there really any reason / advantage for me to use useCallback to cache the function in my custom hook? I read the docs, but I just coudln't grasp the idea behind this usage of useCallback. How exactly it memoizes the function between renders? How exactly does ti work, and should I use it?
2. Inside the same custom hook, you can see the new values state being updated by spreading the previous state and creating a new object like so: `setValues(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));`
   Would there be any difference if I did this instead? `setValues({ ...prev, [name]: value })`
   as far as I can tell, doesn't look like it has any difference right? I am simply accessing the state directly.. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question:

In your case it doesn't matter because everything is rendered in the same component. If you have a list of things that get an event handler then useCallback can save you some renders.

In the example below the first 2 items are rendered with an onClick that is re created every time App re renders. This will not only cause the Items to re render it will also cause virtual DOM compare to fail and React will re create the Itms in the DOM (expensive operation).

The last 2 items get an onClick that is created when App mounts and not re created when App re renders so they will never re render.

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useRef, memo } = React;
const Item = memo(function Item({ onClick, id }) {
  const rendered = useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  return (
    <button _id={id} onClick={onClick}>
      {id} : rendered {rendered.current} times
    </button>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const onClick = (e) =>
    setMessage(
      'last clicked' + e.target.getAttribute('_id')
    );
  const memOnClick = useCallback(onClick, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{message}</h3>
      {[1, 2].map((id) => (
        <Item key={id} id={id} onClick={onClick} />
      ))}
      {[1, 2].map((id) => (
        <Item key={id} id={id} onClick={memOnClick} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Another example is when you want to call a function in an effect that also needs to be called outside of the effect so you can't put the function inside the effect. You only want to run the effect when a certain value changes so you can do something like this.

```
//fetchById is (re) created when ID changes
const fetchById = useCallback(
  () => console.log('id is', ID),
  [ID]
);
//effect is run when fetchById changes so basically
//  when ID changes
useEffect(() => fetchById(), [fetchById]);
```

Your second question:

The `setValues({ ...prev, [name]: value })` will give you an error because you never defined pref but if you meant: `setValues({ ...values, [name]: value })` and wrap the handler in a useCallback then now your callback has a dependency on `values` and will be needlessly be re created whenever values change.

If you don't provide the dependency then the linter will warn you and you end up with a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). Here is an example of the stale closure as counter.count will never go up because you never re create onClick after the first render thus the counter closure will always be `{count:1}`.

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useRef } = React;
const App = () => {
  const [counts, setCounts] = useState({ count: 1 });
  const rendered = useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  const onClick = useCallback(
    //this function is never re created so counts.count is always 1
    //  every time it'll do setCount(1+1) so after the first
    //  click this "stops working"
    () => setCounts({ count: counts.count + 1 }),
    [] //linter warns of missing dependency count
  );
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>
      count: {counts.count} rendered:{rendered.current}
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: As for the 2nd question, yes I meant `setValues({ ...values, [name]: value })`.
Let's say i am not using useCallback to wrap it, is there any difference between this and doing `setValues(prev=> ({...prev, [name]: value}))` ?

Comment: @kevkev If you want to wrap `setValues({ ...values, [name]: value })` in a useCallback then you needlessly create a dependency `values`, to ignore this dependency will create a stale closure as with the example above (counter example). There is no difference if you don't wrap it in a useCallback or any other memoizing hook but then you will needlessly re render child components. It won't in your example because you don't have child components.