# Endless refresh in auth process with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I would like to implement an auth process with React and React Router that it calls API to refresh token when route is changed every time but met an endless refresh.

```
const location = useLocation(); // react-router

const [auth, setAuth] = useState({ accessToken: 'aaa', refreshToken: 'bbb' }); // token-based auth

const refresh = useCallback(async () => {
  const response = await fetch(url, auth.accessToken, auth.refreshToken); // pseudo code
  const body = await response.json();
  setAuth({ accessToken: body.accessToken, refreshToken: body.refreshToken });
}, [auth, setAuth]);

useEffect(() => {
  Promise.resolve().then(refresh);
}, [location.pathname, refresh]);
```

When route (`location.pathname`) is changed,

`useEffect` is invoked (as it depends on `location.pathname`),

`auth` is updated (through `setAuth`),

`refresh` is updated (as it depends on `auth`),

`useEffect` is invoked again (as it depends on `refresh`), and then this goes on and on.

The recursive dependencies between `auth` and `refresh` causes this endless loop. How could this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following looks a bit wonky but will remove the `auth` dependency from the callback. If user changes location quicker than fetch finishes you may not set auth in the same order as the location changed so I hope that is not a problem:

```
const refresh = useCallback(() => {
  setAuth((auth) => {
    fetch(url, auth.accessToken, auth.refreshToken)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((body) =>
        setAuth({
          accessToken: body.accessToken,
          refreshToken: body.refreshToken,
        })
      );
    return auth;
  });
}, []);//no dependencies
```

Answer (score 2):

Paste my final code for reference based on HMR's answer, thanks.

```
const fetchAuth = useCallback(async ({ accessToken, refreshToken }) => {
  const resp = await fetch(...);
  const body = await resp.json();
  return {
    accessToken: body.accessToken,
    refreshToken: body.refreshToken,
  };
}, []);

const onRouteChange = useCallback(async () => {
  setAuth((auth) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      const accessToken = auth.accessToken;
      const refreshToken = auth.refreshToken;
      const newAuth = await fetchAuth({ accessToken, refreshToken });
      setAuth(newAuth);
    }, 100);
    return auth;
  });
}, [fetchAuth]);

useEffect(() => {
  onRouteChange();
}, [location.pathname, onRouteChange]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since:

- `refresh` function execution changes the value of `auth`.
- Different `auth` trigger `refresh` function execution again.
- Starts the process again

For me passing refresh to the main `useEffect` doesnt make sense

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Promise.resolve().then(refresh); // This Promise is useful. Just call the function
  refresh()
}, [location.pathname]); // remove refresh from here
```

Your `refresh` function doesnt make sense anyway. Shouldnt be using the initial values of `auth` state.

Comment: Now refresh will be a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) an example of that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61331791/1641941) (last code example in the answer) that should answer your `For me passing refresh to the main useEffect doesnt make sense `

Answer (score 0):

Everything you put on the dependencies, makes the component to refresh on change. Basically your callback was refreshing auth every times that auth was new. And here you see the loop!

Btw. you don't need to put setAuth as deps, because it is a constant that never changes!

```js
const refresh = useCallback(async () => {
  setAuth((auth)=>{
  const response = await fetch(url, auth.accessToken, auth.refreshToken); // pseudo code
  const body = await response.json();
    return { accessToken: body.accessToken, refreshToken: body.refreshToken }
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: You can't set `auth` to a promise, OP is trying to use it later as auth. accessToken and you didn't mark the callback as async so it'll produce an error.

Comment: You are right, i didn't try the code, it was just an example. You can easily change the async with a promise or calling them with the then().catch().finally() functions

Comment: That is why I used `setAuth((auth) => {
    fetch()
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((body) =>
        setAuth({
          accessToken: body.accessToken,
          refreshToken: body.refreshToken,
        })
      );
    return auth;
  });` in my answer. It returns auth to the first setAuth (causing no re renders) and when promise resolves it calls setAuth with the resolve value.